# Flask Mail Bad Header Error Assign Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, backend, flask-mail

```
def verification():
    global ver_pw
    list_pw = []

email_list = []
email_list.append(email)
print(email_list)
    for _ in range(0,4):
        randomly = random.randint(0,1)
        if randomly == 0:
            letter = random.choice(letterslow)
        else:
            letter = random.choice(lettersupper)
        list_pw.append(letter)
    ver_pw = ''.join(map(str, list_pw))
    text = "Herzlich wilkommen " + username + " bei Crypto Bank ihre verschlüsselte Bank, die Wert auf Sicherheit und Verschlüsselung legt.\n Bitte geben sie den Folgenden Verifizierungscode ein um Sicherzustellen, dass dies auch ihre Email Adresse ist." + ver_pw
    mail.send_message(text, sender = 'noah.server.dev@gmail.com', recipients=email_list, body="Verification")
    return "mail sent"
```

At mail.sendmessage it gives me an error but when i change the variable text with 'test' it works fine i also tried subject=text . How can i assing a variable as paramenter usually it works fine but here not.

Comment: Good question, Gave it an upvote

Answer (score 0):

I found the error you cannot use \n

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of**

```
text = "Herzlich wilkommen " + username + " bei Crypto Bank ihre verschlüsselte Bank, die Wert auf Sicherheit und Verschlüsselung legt.\n Bitte geben sie den Folgenden Verifizierungscode ein um Sicherzustellen, dass dies auch ihre Email Adresse ist." + ver_pw
```

**TRY THIS**

```
text = f"""Herzlich wilkommen {username} bei Crypto Bank ihre verschlüsselte Bank, die Wert auf Sicherheit und Verschlüsselung legt.
Bitte geben sie den Folgenden Verifizierungscode ein um Sicherzustellen, dass dies auch ihre Email Adresse ist.""" + ver_pw
```